# Do we need to create non-retina images?

Tags: ios, iphone, retina-display

The actual question is: do I need to create non-retina images if my app should only work on iPhone5/s and iOS >= 7.0?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only targeting iOS 7 iPhones, you will be fine using only retina images. Your app will be able to run on an iPad though and if it does not properly, your app will get rejected. Make sure to include an app icon for iPads, which is 76x76 points, so 152x152 pixels.

Comment: why should my app be tested on iPad if I am writing an iPhone app?

Comment: Apple allows users to download iPhone only apps on an iPad, but you shouldn't have to alter any code to support an iPad (usually). An iOS 7 iPad uses the retina iPhone graphics.

Answer (score 2):

- No need of **non retina** images.
- Non retina images may be used only for the **non retina devices** like iphone 3gs .

Comment: Just found this one: http://www.iosres.com/ , do I need to write "-568@2x" or use simple name without any prefixes/postfixes?

Comment: -568 for only xcode default images. Just use "name@2x.png" format. its enough, don't confuse yourself.

Comment: Accept my answer if you satisfied. @AndrewShmig